# preventDefault() stops form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

having a problem with browser form validation using .preventDefault()

Is there a way to let browser check validation of required inputs, but stops submit?

Is there any flags I can use to get if form is valid?

Thanks

update:
using both backbone and jquery

```
events: {
    "click #commentFormSubmit": "commentFormSubmit",
},
commentFormSubmit: function(el){
    el.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(el.target).parent();

    // this.$el.find('button').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
    var commentData = {};
    commentData.name = this.$el.find('input[name=comment_name]').val();
    commentData.country = this.$el.find('input[name=comment_country]').val();
    commentData.email = this.$el.find('input[name=comment_email]').val();
    commentData.comment = this.$el.find('textarea[name=comment_text]').val();
    commentData.grade = this.$el.find('.commnt_grade:checked').val();
    console.log('dd')
    this.model.onSubmitComment(commentData);
},
```

and the form:

```
    <form action="" class="" method="post">
        <span>
            <input type="text" name="comment_name" class="comment_input" placeholder="{{ 'your name'|_ }}" required>
            <input type="text" name="comment_country" class="comment_input" placeholder="{{ 'country'|_ }}">
            <input type="text" name="comment_email" class="comment_input" placeholder="{{ 'your email'|_ }}" required>
        </span>

        <textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="{{ 'your comment'|_ }}" required></textarea>
        <span class="grades">

            <input type="radio" name="commnt_grade" class="commnt_grade" id="grade_1" value="1">
            <label for="grade_1" class="selectGrades" data-eq="1"></label>

            <input type="radio" name="commnt_grade" class="commnt_grade" id="grade_2" value="2">
            <label for="grade_2" class="selectGrades" data-eq="2"></label>

            <input type="radio" name="commnt_grade" class="commnt_grade" id="grade_3" value="3">
            <label for="grade_3" class="selectGrades" data-eq="3"></label>

            <input type="radio" name="commnt_grade" class="commnt_grade" id="grade_4" value="4">
            <label for="grade_4" class="selectGrades" data-eq="4"></label>

            <input type="radio" name="commnt_grade" class="commnt_grade" id="grade_5" value="5">
            <label for="grade_5" class="selectGrades" data-eq="5"></label>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" id="commentFormSubmit">{{ 'submit'|_ }}</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: do you use any frameworks? or plain JS?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: using couple frameworks. edited question.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to validate without submitting, you can get the browser to *check* the validity of the form by calling `checkValidity` on it, and to *report* the validity by calling `reportValidity`. (On browsers that support HTML validation.)

Calling both checks and then reports, without submitting:

```
yourFormElement.checkValidity();
yourFormElement.reportValidity();
```

Example:

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  var yourFormElement = $("form")[0];
  yourFormElement.checkValidity();
  yourFormElement.reportValidity();
});
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" required>
<br><input type="text" required>
<br><input type="button" value="Click to check">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also do it at the individual element level:

```
yourInputElement.checkValidity();
yourInputElement.reportValidity();
```

Example:

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  var yourInputElement = $("#second")[0];
  yourInputElement.checkValidity();
  yourInputElement.reportValidity();
});
```

```html
<form>
<input id="first" type="text" required>
<br><input id="second" type="text" required>
<br><input type="button" value="Click to check second field only">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since you've mentioned you're using jQuery, I'll just emphasize that these are methods of the DOM element, not the jQuery object. So for instance, if your form has an `id` and you look it up like this:

```
var $myForm = $("#the-form");
```

then you'd use

```
$myForm[0].checkValidity();
$myForm[0].reportValidity();
```

**not**

```
$myForm.checkValidity();  // Wrong
$myForm.reportValidity(); // Wrong
```

Or you could give yourself a little plugin for it:

```
jQuery.fn.checkValidity = function() {
    var el = this[0];
    return el && el.checkValidity();
};
jQuery.fn.reportValidity = function() {
    var el = this[0];
    return el && el.reportValidity();
};
```

That's in keeping with jQuery's various other "getters" in that it only looks at the first element in the set inside the jQuery object.

Comment: what if i have 5 fields?

Comment: @aleXela: Call it on the form. Oddly enough, I'd just realized I hadn't said that and was editing the above as you commented; hit refresh. :-)

Comment: and there no simple way to do it?? wired.

Comment: @aleXela: What's not simple about two function calls on the form element?

Comment: i tried to use checkValidity() for some reason its not working. i think i'm referencing wrong object.
and i need to run this code for all input objects.

Comment: @aleXela: Working examples above. Remember, checking and reporting are different things. Also remember these are methods on the DOM element; if you're looking up the element with jQuery, do as the examples above do and access the DOM element inside the jQuery object via `[0]`.

Comment: $el.find('input')[0].checkValidity() works.
and need to run each for this.
that's not simple here, is that browser has this feature (validation) i only want to run my models' method after validation give OK.

Comment: @aleXela: Again: If you want to check all of the inputs in a form, call the methods on the form.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please mention that `checkValidity()` and `reportValidity()` are mutual exclusive. Both invoke validation on the form elements (`<input>`) while only `reportValidity()` triggers the browser native visual reporting. `checkValidity()` is used when you want to provide your own visual reporting. You should **never** use these two methods together. Both methods returns a boolean.

Answer (score 7):

While @TJ provided a good solution in his answer, the alternative method is to listen for the `submit` event on the actual form while using `event.preventDefault()`. This will allow the form validation to trigger but prevent the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @T.J. Crowder for the direction.
as for me it's a fix, not a solution.

```
commentFormSubmit: function(el){
    var $el = $(el.target).parent();    
    if ($el[0].checkValidity()){
        el.preventDefault();
        // this.$el.find('button').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
        var commentData = {};
        commentData.name = this.$el.find('input[name=comment_name]').val();
        commentData.country = this.$el.find('input[name=comment_country]').val();
        commentData.email = this.$el.find('input[name=comment_email]').val();
        commentData.comment = this.$el.find('textarea[name=comment_text]').val();
        commentData.grade = this.$el.find('.commnt_grade:checked').val();
        // this.model.onSubmitComment(commentData);
    }
    else $el[0].reportValidity();
},
```

Again, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

You can always rely to HTML5 form validation attributes that prevents you to submit your request while you have invalid form data:

- disabled
- max
- min
- pattern
- required

So you do not need to prevent default behavior - use can't submit form until you have invalid data.

```
<form action="/action_page_post.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fname" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp