# page refreshes instead of submitting form when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am having an issue with my react.js / bootstrap app where my new users form is not submitting. I originally used e.preventDefault(), but this caused my form to not validate, so I removed it. Now, my form validates, however, when I click my submit button, the page refreshes and the form is not actually submitted. Any help would be SO appreciated!!

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from '../../api/axios';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import UserList from './UserList';

function UserForm({ user, setUser }) {
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState("");

    const changeVal = async (key, value) => {
        setUser(user => ({ ...user, [key]: value }));
    }

    /*Determines whether the user being created is an admin*/
    let [isAdmin, setAdmin] = useState("true");
    /*Determines whether the user being created is a driver*/
    let [isDriver, setDriver] = useState("false");

    const handleForm = async (e) => {

       // e.preventDefault();

        if (!user.employee_id) { //If the employee ID is blank, a new user is being added.
            try {
                const newUser = {
                    is_admin: isAdmin, is_driver: isDriver, employee_first_name: user.employee_first_name, employee_last_name: user.employee_last_name,
                    employee_username: user.employee_username, employee_contact_no: user.employee_contact_no, 
                    employee_street_address: user.employee_street_address, employee_password: 'testing123', employee_city: user.employee_city, employee_state: user.employee_state, employee_zip_code: user.employee_zip_code, 
                    employee_email: user.employee_email
                };
                let data = JSON.stringify(newUser);
                console.log(data);
                const response = await axios.post('/employee', data, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
                );
                //fetchItem();

            } catch (err) {
                setErrMsg(JSON.stringify(err));
                return;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                const newUser = {
                    employee_id: user.employee_id, is_admin: isAdmin, is_driver: isDriver, employee_first_name: user.employee_first_name, employee_last_name: user.employee_last_name,
                    employee_username: user.employee_username, employee_password: user.employee_password, employee_contact_no: user.employee_contact_no,
                    employee_street_address: user.employee_street_address,
                    employee_city: user.employee_city, employee_state: user.employee_state, employee_zip_code: user.employee_zip_code,
                    employee_email: user.employee_email
                };
                let data = JSON.stringify(newUser);
                console.log(data);
                const response = await axios.put('/employee', data, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
                );
                //fetchItem();

            } catch (err) {
                setErrMsg(JSON.stringify(err));
                return;
            }
        }



    }

    return (

        <React.Fragment>
            {!errMsg ? <> {
                <div className="form-container">
                    <div className='employee-id'>
                        <label htmlFor='ID'>EMPLOYEE #</label>
                        <input className="form-control" id="ID" readOnly value={user.employee_id}></input>
                    </div>
                    <form className='employee-details' data-transport-order="form">
                        <div className='form-group'>
                            <label htmlFor='UserFName'>* FIRST NAME</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="employee_first_name" required value={user.employee_first_name} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserLName'>* LAST NAME</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_last_name" required value={user.employee_last_name} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='Username'>* USERNAME</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_username" required value={user.employee_username} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserPassword'>PASSWORD</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="UserPassword" readOnly></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserContactNo'>* CONTACT #</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_contact_no" required value={user.employee_contact_no} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserAddress'> STREET ADDRESS</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_street_address" value={user.employee_street_address} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserCity'> CITY</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_city" value={user.employee_city} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserState'>STATE</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_state" value={user.employee_state} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserZip'>ZIP CODE</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_zip_code" value={user.employee_zip_code} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserEmail'>EMAIL</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="example@gmail/yahoo.com" pattern=".+@(gmail|yahoo)\.com" className="form-control" id="employee_email" value={user.employee_email} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                        </div>

                        
                            {
                                <div key={`default-checkbox`} className="mb-3" >
                                    <Form.Check
                                        type={'checkbox'}
                                        onChange={() => {
                                            if (isAdmin === "false" && isDriver === "true"){ //If the checkbox is already checked, user is Admin. 
                                                setDriver("false");
                                                setAdmin("true");
                                            }
                                            else { //If the checkbox is already checked, user is Driver.
                                                setDriver("true");
                                                setAdmin("false");
                                            }}
                                        } 
                                        id={`default-checkbox`}
                                        label={`Is Driver`}  
                                    />
                                </div>
                            }
                        
                        <button type="save" className={"btn btn-primary"} onClick={(e) => handleForm(e)}>SAVE</button>
                        <button type="reset" className={"btn btn-primary"} onClick={() =>window.location.reload()}>BACK</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

            }  </> : <>

                <h1>{errMsg}</h1>
            </>}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default UserForm;
```

EDIT: With the comment suggestions, I changed the button's code to:

```
<button type="submit" className={"btn btn-primary"}>SAVE</button>
```

And the form's code to:

```
<form onSubmit = {handleForm} className='employee-details' data-transport-order="form">
```

But the page is still refreshing :(

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372822/preventdefault-stops-form-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change :**

```
 <form className='employee-details' data-transport-order="form">
```

**to :**

```
 <form onSubmit = {handleForm} className='employee-details' data-transport-order="form">
```

**and change  :**

```
<button type="save" className={"btn btn-primary"} onClick={(e) => handleForm(e)}>SAVE</button>
```

**to :**

```
<button type="submit" className={"btn btn-primary"} >SAVE</button>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for responding- I did both of those and receive this error: 

"A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components"

Did I code something else wrong too?

Comment: Please ignore my last message- I just had to restart my webpage!! Everything works exactly as I needed!! Thank you SO much!!

Answer (score 1):

**Change following in your code to below**

`<form className='employee-details' onSubmit={handleForm} data-transport-order="form">`

```
<button type="submit" className={"btn btn-primary"} >SAVE</button>
```

**Then uncomment e.preventDefault()**

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for responding- I did both of those and receive this error: 

"A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components"

Did I code something else wrong too?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the double message- it seemed like I had to restart my server- everything works as expected!! THANK YOU SO MUCH.